# MATE panel not showing

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, mate-panel

21.04 MATE up to date today.

My MATE desktop comes up without panels. Each time I have to issue

```
$ mate-panel reset
```

This restores the panel but also displays the message

```
Unable to open desktop file screensaver.toggle.desktop for panel launcher
Unable to open desktop file timer.desktop for panel launcher
Unable to open desktop file display.flip.desktop for panel launcher
Unable to open desktop file /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop for panel launcher: No such file or directory
Unable to open desktop file /usr/share/mate/applications/spotify.desktop for panel launcher: No such file or directory
....
Unable to open desktop file caja-1.desktop for panel launcher
Unable to open desktop file caja-2.desktop for panel launcher
```

However from this list I can find these files :

```
 /usr/share/**mate**/applications/spotify.desktop 
./.local/share/applications/timer.desktop
```

The only panel references in the journal are about successful activation.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Except that I have to reboot 2x in order to get the panels back.  Not even sure which logs to look in to get a hint.

Comment: @ChrisCurvey Perhaps `/var/log/lightdm/*log`

Answer (score 4):

To reset MATE Panel you can use one of the methods below:

- Restart MATE Panel manually with its current settings using `mate-panel --replace &`
- Change panel layout using MATE Tweak (`mate-tweak`) - go to Panel tab and then change panel layout to some other and then back to current
- Backup current MATE Panel configuration by `dconf dump /org/mate/panel/ > ~/dconf-mate-panel` and then reset it using `dconf reset -f /org/mate/panel/` or `mate-panel --reset`

Comment: Thank you.  `replace` results with the same message.  But my concern is not so much the message as it is that the panel does not come up at desktop restart